# How to add user into specific branch in svn subversion (batch script or api)

Tags: svn, version, visualsvn, subversion-edge

Need to add user to a specific branch command line?

I need to create a batch script or a stand alone application to add user to specific branch to SVN.

Any help?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by adding a user to a branch.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: do you want to create user specific branches and set permissions on those paths? Example: `UserA` can commit on `branches/UserA` and `UserB` can commit on `branches/UserB` ??

Answer (score 0):

There **are not** such thing as "user of specific branch" in SVN concepts at all

You have to use server-specific authentication method and restrict to some authorized users access to some trees on repository. In common case you have to use [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) and **add relevant strings to text-file** with  your access rules